# Can't change tint color of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I started using UINavigationController in My project and there is a problem : I can set the barTintColor, but the tintColor is doesn't changing, always black...

So, the code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(95/255.0) green:(136/255.0) blue:(180/255.0) alpha:(255.0)];
    }
```

**NEW :** Hey, maybe my english is not good, but I'll repeat : **I can't set the TINTCOLOR, not the barTintColor!**

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationController or just a UINavigationBar object? Let me know.

Comment: @MichaelOrtiz UINavigationController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go sir. Just put this in your viewDidLoad method.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(95/255.0) green:(136/255.0) blue:(180/255.0) alpha:1];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
```

Comment: nice and tidy!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try..

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:106/255.0f green:195/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

You must set it in the navigation controller, not directly in the navigation bar, so it affects all the view controllers inside the navigation controller.